# managing 3 storyboards in app delegate

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I found this link [Managing two storyboards in App Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25465996/2405489)

does this apply to three storyboards ?

i'm using xcode 6.3.2 with swift

Comment: In the future, try to write better questions so you don't get down voted and are a responsible member of the community :) This means elaborating on what you have tried already, being as specific as possible with your question and following all the guidelines specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  That applies to 3 storyboards, or 30 storyboards, or 3 ^ 30 ^ 30 ^ 3 Storyboards.  However, the logic of that question was premised on wanting to use different storyboards for different specific sizes, which is not really good practice.  Apple wants us to use autosizing, anchors etc. to make out scoreboards autoresize based on device.  This is better for Apple (gives them more flexibility to release new stuff) and better for us devs (less pressure to update apps to accommodate new product lines).  You can find elaborate explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) and beyond.